# How to add a number to a portion of dataframe column in pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns A and B.

```
A        B
1        0
2        0
3        1
4        2
5        0
6        3
```

What I want to do is to add column A with with column B. But only with the corresponding non zero values of column B. And put the result on column B.

```
A        B
1        0
2        0
3        4
4        6
5        0
6        9
```

Thank you for your help and sugestion in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use `.loc` with a boolean mask:

```
In [49]:
df.loc[df['B'] != 0, 'B'] = df['A'] + df['B']
df

Out[49]:
   A  B
0  1  0
1  2  0
2  3  4
3  4  6
4  5  0
5  6  9
```